# "I have to watch my friend playing/play chess."

Tags: catenative-verbs

I was just making a joke about something and I said: "I have to watch my friend playing chess." is that correct or should I have used "play" instead of "playing"

Answer (score 2):

For verbs of perception like *watch*, we can use either the *infinitive without to* or *the -ing* form after the object verbs.

For *watch*, the former is more common, as [shown in Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Watch+him+play%2Cwatch+him+playing+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2CWatch%20him%20play%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwatch%20him%20play%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWatch%20him%20play%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwatch%20him%20playing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwatch%20him%20playing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWatch%20him%20playing%3B%2Cc0).

Please see below for further details.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing

> Hear, see, etc. + object + infinitive or -ing

> We can use either the infinitive without to or the -ing form after the object of verbs such as hear, see, notice, watch. The infinitive without to often emphasises the whole action or event which someone hears or sees. The -ing form usually emphasises an action or event which is in progress or not yet completed.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

I have to watch my friend **play** chess. (complete action, from beginning to end)

I have to watch my friend **playing** chess. (NOT complete action, in the middle of the action)

[ He crossed the road. I saw this. I saw him cross the road. (Complete action, from beginning to end)

He was crossing the road. I saw this. I saw him crossing the road. (NOT complete action, in the middle of crossing the road)

I heard her sing.- complete action, from beginning to end

I heard her singing.- NOT complete action, in the middle of the action ]

For a shorter action, we can use either (-ing form or infinitive without to).

Comment: "I have to watch my friend play chess" does not imply that the chess playing is complete. "I heard her singing" does not imply that the singing is *currently* incomplete, just that the singing was ongoing in the timeframe when you heard it. The -ing form emphasizes the ongoing nature of the action, but I find this complete/incomplete dichotomy too strict.